# Prove the Inequality: $\vert x_1\vert ^\alpha+\vert x_2\vert ^\alpha\geq\Vert X\Vert _2 ^\alpha$, for $\alpha\in (1,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $X=[x_1,x_2]^T$. If $\alpha\in (1,2)$, then

$$\vert x_1\vert ^\alpha+\vert x_2\vert ^\alpha\geq\Vert X\Vert ^\alpha,$$

where $\vert\cdot\vert$ is the absolute value, and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is the 2-norm.

I am fairly confident that this inequality is true ([here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j5esyke6eh) is a plot), but I am at a lost of how to prove it. I spent some time looking through tables of inequalities but didn't find anything that would help me out in proving this, so I am here looking for some suggestions, insights, or possible routes to take in proving this.

Thanks

For more of a sanity check, I wrote a MATLAB script checking the inequality and found no values for $X$ or $\alpha$ that breaks the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality holds for vectors of arbitrary dimension.

It boils down to
$$
\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_\alpha.
$$
We can equivalently show that $\|y\|_2 \leq 1$ for $y = x/\|x\|_\alpha$.

Note that
$$
\|y\|_2^2 = \sum_j \Big(\Big(\frac{|x_j|}{\|x\|_\alpha}\Big)^\alpha \Big)^{2/\alpha} \leq 1.
$$
The last inequality arises since $u_j = \left(\tfrac{|x_j|}{\|x\|_\alpha}\right)^{\alpha} \leq 1$, so $u_j^{2/\alpha} \leq u_j$, since $2/\alpha \geq 1$. But, $\sum_j u_j = 1$.

Comment: Great, thankyou!